# On symmetries in spin systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, symmetry

I'm reading about concepts related to symmetries in spin systems, and I feel I have some confusions about things that are so obvious that they're never explained. For example, take the AKLT spin chain in its MPS representation

$$ |\psi\rangle\propto\sum_{\mu_{j}\in\{x,y,z\}}|\mu_N\rangle\dots|\mu_1\rangle \mathrm{Tr}(\sigma_{\mu_N}\dots\sigma_{\mu_1})$$

Where $|\mu\rangle$ is such that $S_\mu|\mu\rangle=0$ where $\{\mu\}$ is an orthonotmal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $S_\mu$ generate the spin $1$ representation of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, and where $\sigma_\mu$ are the Pauli matrices (except $\sigma_y=\sigma_x\sigma_z$).  This is the ground state of the Hamiltonian

$$ H=\sum_{j}\mathbf{S}_j\cdot\mathbf{S}_{j+1}+\frac13(\mathbf{S}_j\cdot\mathbf{S}_{j+1})^2  $$

It is often said that the AKLT model has $SO(3)$ symmetry. What does this mean? Does it mean that

$$U|\psi\rangle:=e^{-i\theta_1S_{k_1}}\otimes e^{-i\theta_2S_{k_2}} \otimes \dots \otimes e^{-i\theta_NS_{k_N}}|\psi\rangle=|\psi\rangle$$
for any $\theta_j$ and $k_j\in\{x,y,z\}$? Or does it mean that $[U,H]=0$? Are those two the same or does one imply the other?

In general, what do people mean when they say a spin system has a given symmetry?

Comment: The inner product is invariant under a isometry: let $A \in SO(3)$ then $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^3: (Ax)\cdot (Ay)=x\cdot y$. So the Hamiltonian is invariant under $SO(3)$. That is what is meant. Physically this means that you can rotate all the spins by the same angle and then the energy will still be the same since the relative orientation did not change.

Comment: @Dani So it means that if I apply the *same* element of $SO(3)$ to every site, the Hamiltonian doesn't change? Does this necessarily imply that the ground state is invariant under said transformation? It seems to me that the MPS I wrote down actually satisfies $U|\psi\rangle$=|\psi\rangle$ for the $U$ I wrote down, which has a differens $SO(3)$ transformation for every site. Is that just a peculiarity of the AKLT state?

Comment: correction to formatting of previous comment: It seems to me that the MPS I wrote down actually satisfies $U|\psi\rangle=|\psi \rangle$, where $U$ has a different $SO(3)$ transformation for every site. Is that just a peculiarity of the AKLT state?

Comment: You map all spins with the same element of $SO(3)$: that is true. I am not sure whether the ground-state is invariant, I think it is since the Hamiltonian is also invariant.